# jquery index of particular class

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have this HTML:

```
<div>

  <div class="ClassA"></div>
  <div class="ClassX"></div>
  <div class="ClassB"></div>
  <div class="ClassC"></div>
  <div class="ClassX"></div>
  <div class="ClassA"></div>
  <div class="ClassX"></div>

</div>
```

I'm looking to get the order of ClassX when I click on it. For instance, if I click on the first ClassX, it should return 1 and if I click on the second ClassX it should return 2.

```
$('.ClassX').click(function () {

  var TheOrder = 0;

  //code here for TheOrder

  alert(TheOrder);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) with a selector:

```
$('.ClassX').click(function () {

  var TheOrder = $(this).index(".ClassX") + 1; // index is 0-based.

  alert(TheOrder);

});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kykWr/

Answer (score 2):

Define a subset of the ClassX elements, then use this subset to get the index of the clicked element, like so:

```
var $elements = $('.ClassX');

$elements.click(function ()
{
  var i = $elements.index(this);
  console.log(i);
});
```